# Обучение системному администрированию MySQL

Tags: mysql, сервер, веб-сервер

Всем привет, такая ситуация. Хочу научится работать с серверами, стать системным администратором. Сам я в этом деле пока что полной ноль. Единственный сервер который я ставил это Denwer на локальный компьютер.

Кто знаком с этим делом, подскажите с чего начинать, и можно ли потренироваться делать все это на локальном компьютере. Опыт создания сайтов имею. С языком MySQl знакомый. Просто вот не знаю с чего начать. Куда копать?

За помощь за ранние благодарю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Системный администратор MySQL - очень специализированная ниша, даже экспертного знания об ней может оказаться не достаточно, чтобы трудоустроиться. Хотя любой эксперт в области MySQL знает довольно много о сопутствующих технологиях. Вам так же придется изучить многое, не связанное напрямую с MySQL.

Сразу хочется предупредить о подводном камне: в силу "полит-экономических" причин MySQL в ближайшее время сдаст позиции в IT-сообществе. Дело в том, что из-за серии слияний СУБД оказалась в руках корпорации Oracle. Учитывая, что InnoDB строилась как менее дорогостоящая замена Oracle, это не очень хорошо для дальнейшего развития СУБД. В связи с этим вряд ли стоит в ближайшее время ожидать бурного развития официальной MySQL (или хотя бы темпа развития образца 2007, СУБД откровенно стагнацирует). Есть альтернативные компании, которые развивают технологии на базе MySQL - MariaDB, Perconа, на них стоит обратить пристальное внимание. Однако, лучше не ориентироваться лишь на MySQL, изучайте также PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL, NoSQL-решения. Это вас здорово обезопасит в пане будущего трудоустройства.

Если я вас не отговорил ориентироваться на MySQL, следует обратить внимание на следующие моменты (на самом деле их гораздо больше, я перечислю лишь часть):

- операционные системы: необходимо изучать *nix-системы во всех проявлениях, так как большинство инсталляций будет на UNIX-подобных операционных системах. Знание операционных систем и способность их администрировать пригодится вам в работе больше, чем даже знание MySQL; Хорошо бы знать bash, vim, sed, awk, подсистему прав доступа и модификации в современных дистрибутивах;
- логгирование - syslog, nagios, zabbix и т.п.;
- репликация, ставьте несколько виртуальных машин (VirtualBox, vagrant) и экспериментируйте. Репликация в MySQL довольно капризная и часто ломается. Чем больше у вас будет опыта по работе с ней, тем лучше; Репликация служит основой для масштабирования и надежного резервного копирования - копии баз данных лучше снимать с холодной реплики, чем с нагруженного сервера, в тяжелой базе данных ALTER-запросы выполняются сутками, в общем репликацию придется освоить. Бинарные журналы - это тоже часть механизма репликации.
- мониторинг, тоже большей частью относится к nix*.

На русский язык переведены две замечательные книги

- MySQL. Оптимизация производительности. Бэрон Шварц, Петр Зайцев и др.
  Символ-плюс, 2010.
- Обеспечение высокой доступности систем на основе
  MySQL. Чарльз Белл, Мэтс Киндал, Ларс Таллманн. Русская редакция,
  БХВ, 2012.

Хорошо бы с ними ознакомиться. В идеале знакомиться со всей новой литературой, выходящей на английском.

Есть еще один подводный камень: работая системным администратором велик соблазн не писать код и не участвовать в разработке приложений. Хорошо бы хоть немного кодировать, чтобы "чувствовать" приложения и ориентироваться в трудоемкости тех или иных решений на стороне разработчика. Для этого нужно освоить хотя бы один скриптовый язык (не bash/perl, лучше если это будет python). Его знание пригодится и для решения административных задач.

Comment: чет я так и не понял, с чего начинать, ну кроме как книг и языков.

Comment: Ubuntu, виртуальные машины, книги. Арендуйте VPS, купите домен и администрируйте свой собственный сервер, настройте базу, Web-интерфейс, то же phpMyAdmin, настройте Redmine себе для постановке себе задач, настройте почту, настройте Gitlab, разверните свой блог на VPS. Вынесите проекты на поддомены третьего уровня. Сделайте резервное копирование баз данных всех проектов. Настройте почтовые уведомления. Организуйте ротацию логов. Если для решения задач не хватает каких-то скилов - прокачивайте.

Comment: спасибо, теперь туман немного разсеялся. Буду разбиратся дальше.

Comment: Возражаю. Совсем необязательно покупать домен и хостинг, чтобы учиться системному администрированию. )

Comment: Не обязательно :) но если бюджет позволяет, так мне кажется будет интереснее и возможно быстрее.